# Data inserts automatically when I refresh the page ?

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-3

I have 2 textboxs and a button.

The target is to save textbox data on the button click and empty the textbox so that it gets ready for the next entry.

The problem is even though the textbox looks empty after the button click. If I refresh the page, the last inserted value automatically inserts into the database.

page code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Time").val("");
    $("#Title").val("");
});

</script>
<%Html.EnableClientValidation(); %>
<% using (Html.BeginForm())
{ %>
<div id="fullform">
<h2>Enter the program list</h2>
<div id="CreateData">
    <div>
        <%:Html.LabelFor(m=>m.Year) %>
    </div>
    <div>
        <%:Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.Year) %>
    </div>
    <div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><%:Html.LabelFor(m=>m.Time) %></td>
                <td><%:Html.LabelFor(m=>m.Title) %></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><%:Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Time)%></td>
                <td><%:Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.Title) %></td>
                <td><input type="image" value="Register"     src="../../Content/images/btnAdd.png"/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

What am I doing wrong??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect your problem might be caused by the page refresh itself, which could re-posting your previous data to the server.

After your page has posted the data could you redirect to a different page?

There's further info on data reposts after a page refresh in a Wikipedia article here - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

Comment: No I cannot redirect to a different page since the inserted data is going to display at the bottom

Comment: I think you could still use the Post/Redirect/Get pattern, see this blog post for an asp.net MVC specific example - http://www.stevefenton.co.uk/Content/Blog/Date/201104/Blog/ASP-NET-MVC-Post-Redirect-Get-Pattern/